# Why does my code keep on looping like this when I'm using functions?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a Hangman console game and im trying to check how many tries I have left and then later add a game over function if tries left. One part of it is working the **stringcount** function is working properly until I have to call the **goAgain** function, I'll explain the issue lower in the document

```
import time

hangmanSolved = "What 'eva hh"
chosingletter = input("Input a letter you would like to try! ")

def goAgain(defaultTries):
    defaultTries -= 1
    print("Head drawn!", defaultTries, "tries left ")
    stringcount()

# if a letter is in, and how many letters are in
def stringcount():
    count = 0

    lettersIn = hangmanSolved.count(chosingletter)
    for i in hangmanSolved:
        if i == chosingletter:
            count = count + 1
            
    if not count:
        print("There are no ", chosingletter, "'s in this sentence! ")
        time.sleep(1)
        goAgain(defaultTries=5)
    elif count == 1:
        print("There is only one ", chosingletter, " in this sentence! ")
    else:
        print("There is ", lettersIn, chosingletter, "'s in this sentence! ")

stringcount()
```

When I run the code and guess a wrong letter, or rather when I have to call **goAgain** function it keeps on looping me this output:

```
Input a letter you would like to try! j
There are no  j 's in this sentence! 
Head drawn! 4 tries left 
There are no  j 's in this sentence! 
Head drawn! 4 tries left
```

How can I fix this looping, and the tries counter?!?

Comment: Don't use recursion in place of looping.

Comment: `defaultTries` is a local variable in each function. Subtracting it in `goAgain()` doesn't change the value in `stringcount()`

Comment: In goAgain() you are calling stringcount() again, which sets count again at 0, which makes condition `if not count` True. This causes an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

So first of all the counter is wrong because you are using a local variable. When the method is called with defaultTries = 5 it will always start at 5 even though you have done defaultTries -= 1.

To fix this you need to read up and assign a global variable outside of the scope so that whenever the user is wrong that global variable gets subtracted.

Furthermore, I am unsure as to why you would use the time module here. What is your goal by doing this?

What you are trying to do is loop through the sentence and check if the letter the user inputs exists inside the sentence. There are easier ways to go about this.

You can use string.indexOf('a'). where 'a' you can change it to the letter you are searching for (the user's input). It returns the index of the first occurrence of the character in the character sequence represented by this object, or -1 if the character does not occur.

I would start with changing those things first!

Comment: Thank you, by the way, the time.sleep, I don't know why its there, I probably didn't delete it when I was fixing up my functions

Answer (score 0):

Every time you call `goAgain` you call it with `defaultTries` set to 5. Then, in that function, it subtracts one, leaving you with 4. Then it calls `stringount` which again calls `goAgain` which will call `stringcount` and so on. There's nothing that breaks out of the loop.

So you need to change three things:

1. Don't pass in the same value of `defaultTries` every time you call `goAgain`. You want to allow that variable to decrease.
2. Git rid of the `goAgain` function. Instead put that logic in `stringcount` itself.
3. Check the value of the number of tries remaining and if it's zero, print out some kind of message, but don't call `stringcount` in that branch.

   ```
   def stringcount(tries = 5):
     count = 0
     tries =- 1
     if tries == 0:
       print("No tries remaining")
     else:
         lettersIn = hangmanSolved.count(chosingletter)
         for i in hangmanSolved:
             if i == chosingletter:
                 count = count + 1

         if not count:
             print("There are no ", chosingletter, "'s in this sentence! ")
             time.sleep(1)
             stringcount(tries)
         elif count == 1:
             print("There is only one ", chosingletter, " in this sentence! ")
         else:
             print("There is ", lettersIn, chosingletter, "'s in this sentence! ")

   stringcount()
   ```

A few other things you can consider changing:

1. The standard formatting in Python is `PEP8` and you should review those. For example, Python convention is to use `snake_case` instead of `camelCase`. So you would use something like `default_tries` instead of `defaultTries` for example.
2. It's probably more explicit to check `if count == 0` than it is to check `if not count`.
3. I think you don't need the loop that updates the variable `count`. Just use `lettersIn` (which you should rename as `letters_in` or, better, just call this `count`). Now you also don't need to set `count==0` at the top of the function.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I need the go again function cause I have a whole turtle code set up in a diff project and the go again function is gonna be responsible for drawing parts of the body seperately

Answer (score 0):

You're having problems because you are basically using a recursive strategy but you haven't defined a base case, and also because you reinitialize your defaultTries variable to 5 every time you call the goAgain() function. A base case is a condition where you tell a recursive function to stop. In this case tries needs to be 0. Here's an example of what your code might look like:

```
def goAgain(tries):
    tries -= 1
    if tries==0:
        print("You lose")
        return None
    
    print("Head drawn!", tries, "tries left ")
    stringcount(tries)


def stringcount(defaultTries=5): #This is how you set default args
    chosingletter = input("Input a letter you would like to try! ")
    count = 0

    lettersIn = hangmanSolved.count(chosingletter)
    for i in hangmanSolved:
        if i == chosingletter:
            count = count + 1
            

    if not count:
        print("There are no ", chosingletter, "'s in this sentence! ")
        time.sleep(1)
        goAgain(defaultTries)
```

It's up to you whether you want to keep goAgain() and stringcount() separate. I think it makes sense to keep them separate because I can imagine you want to check how many tries are in goAgain and then print new statements accordingly, like "left arm drawn!" etc.